# How to Delete list item in React - no errors showing in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping through a function that's getting data and displaying it correctly. What I want to do is to remove an item onclick, but it wouldn't do it and isn't showing any errors. Anyone can spot what's wrong?
*We are getting group from the props.*

```
export default class About extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...props
    };
    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
  }

  delete(item) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      group: prevState.group.filter(tag => tag.id != item.id)
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (

 <div>
                  {
                    this.props.group.map(tag => (
                      <li className={styles.tag} key={tag.id}>
                        <Link to={`/tags/${sluggo(tag.fieldValue)}/#thoughts`}>
                          {tag.fieldValue} ({tag.totalCount})
                              </Link>
                        <span onClick={this.delete.bind(this, tag)}>X</span>
                      </li>
                    ))
                  }
                </div>
)}
}
```

Comment: You're binding the delete function twice. Once in the constructor, then each time `render` is called, you create a new bound function passed to `onClick`.

Comment: You wouldn't need the binding at all if you used an [arrow function class property](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal).

Answer (score 0):

The item is not being deleted, because your `render` function is using the `group` list from `this.props` -

```js
this.props.group.map(tag => (...))
```

instead of `this.state`, which is being manipulated in the `delete(item)` function.

Replacing the above prop with the correct state should allow the delete to work properly -

```js
this.state.group.map(tag => (...))
```

Here is a [demo](https://jscomplete.com/playground/s404784) of the delete functionality working

Comment: I would recommend this answer which should be able to solve your problem directly. But also there is a potential problem in your code that is not related to your question. You copied `props` to your `state` completely, which is not recommended by React. See https://en.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recap